# Fonts in an Android Wear redlines spec provided in pt, but how to conver to sp or dp values?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-fonts

I've been given a redlines design doc for an Android Wear app where the font sizes have been specified in pt.

If the text size in the Wear layout.xml should be specified in dp (or should it be sp?) how do I convert the spec values in pt into equivalent in dp for a *Wearable* app?

Note, I've seen this posting [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) and others but it didn't help me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion between different units follows the same as what you would do on any other Android device. As for SP vs DP, for font size, use SP so it can be scaled correctly if user changes the global font size setting.